# How to have buttons height fill the vertical space of a website?

Tags: html, css

I have a mobile website and it has 3 buttons and a couple of lines of text. I have the text centered (horizontally) and the buttons take up the entire width of the screen. However, I need the height of the buttons to scale to take up the entire screen. How do I make the buttons scale vertically?

```
<p>PROCRASTINATION TIMER v2.0.0</p>

<span id="current">Currently WAITING</span><br/>
<span>Time to Work: </span><span id="work">Not set.</span><br/>
<span>Time to Derp: </span><span id="derp">Not set.</span><br/>

<button onclick="get_workderp_times();" id="startbutton" style="width:100%;height:33%;">Start</button><br/>
<button onclick="switchstatus('Derp');" id="derpbutton" style="width:100%;height:33%;">Derp</button><br/>
<button onclick="switchstatus('Work');" id="workbutton" style="width:100%;height:33%;">Work</button><br/>

<p>Created by Snake Squared Industries</p>
```

This is in chrome with the height set to 33%:

```
style="width:100%;height:33%;"
```

[image: In chrome with height:33%]

This is in chrome without height set:

```
style="width:100%;"
```

[image: In chrome without height]

This is in chrome with height set to 100%:

```
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
```

[image]

(By the way, I checked, the results are the same in IE too...)

Comment: R u using Jquery Mobile Website??? Can u please post the HTML

Comment: I'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the correct way to setup this up...  for clarity, I moved your style attributes in to CSS.

In order to get elements to expand vertically, we need to put them in a container, and force that container to 100%.   Here's the CSS I used...

**CSS**

```
div, p {margin:0px; padding:0px;}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
#top {height:15%;}
#middle {height:75%;}
#bottom {height:10%;}

button {width:100%;height:33%;}
```

And here's the modified HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <p>PROCRASTINATION TIMER v2.0.0</p>
<span id="current">Currently WAITING</span>
        <br/>
<span>Time to Work: </span><span id="work">Not set.</span>
        <br/>
<span>Time to Derp: </span><span id="derp">Not set.</span>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
    <button onclick="get_workderp_imes();" id="startbutton">Start</button>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="switchstatus('Derp');" id="derpbutton">Derp</button>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="switchstatus('Work');" id="workbutton">Work</button>
    <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    <p>Created by Snake Squared Industries</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle to show you the results.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/bX8EU/1/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to change the height properties of the containing elements. Adding `style="height:100%"` to the `<html>`, `<body>`, and a containing div fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set each of the buttons to have a height of 33% which would scale depending on the device... or 30% each and have some margin in between them

```
height:33%;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
height: 100%;
```

will make the height of the button be the same as the height of the screen even if the screen is resized

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... width:100% works, but height:100% doesn't do anything...

Answer (score -5):

A simple:

```
height: "WHATEVER HEIGHT"px;
```

Would certainly do the trick.

Also try

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to align it in the center of your mobile device.

Comment: No, alone it wouldn't, because screen heights change.

Comment: And I want the buttons to scale with text I have and the screen. I can't use absolute values for this.